# how do I find specific tag in xml file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file and I try to find a specific tag in it. but the tags are different in hirechcal sequence. I try to find tag "MotionVectore" and then calculate the average motion vector value for a specific frame type (P, B or I frame). in the following I put part of this XML file:

```
<Picture id="1" poc="1">
    <GOPNr>0</GOPNr>
    <SubPicture structure="0">
        <Slice num="0">
            <Type>0</Type>
            <TypeString>SLICE_TYPE_P</TypeString>
            <NAL>
                <Num>5</Num>
                <Type>1</Type>
                <TypeString>NALU_TYPE_SLICE</TypeString>
                <Length>47048</Length>
            </NAL>
            <MacroBlock num="0">
                <MotionVector list="0">
                    <RefIdx>0</RefIdx>
                    <Difference>
                        <X>184</X>
                        <Y>149</Y>
                    </Difference>
                    <Absolute>
                        <X>184</X>
                        <Y>149</Y>
                    </Absolute>
                </MotionVector>
                <MotionVector list="0">
                    <RefIdx>0</RefIdx>
                    <Difference>
                        <X>10</X>
                        <Y>0</Y>
                    </Difference>
                    <Absolute>
                        <X>194</X>
                        <Y>149</Y>
                    </Absolute>
                </MotionVector>
                <Position>
                    <X>0</X>
                    <Y>0</Y>
                </Position>
                <QP_Y>21</QP_Y>
                <Type>1</Type>
                <TypeString>P_L0_L0_16x8</TypeString>
                <PredModeString>BLOCK_TYPE_P</PredModeString>
                <SkipFlag>0</SkipFlag>
            </MacroBlock>
            <MacroBlock num="1">
                <SubMacroBlock num="0">
                    <Type>0</Type>
                    <TypeString>P_L0_8x8</TypeString>
                    <MotionVector list="0">
                        <RefIdx>0</RefIdx>
                        <Difference>
                            <X>8</X>
                            <Y>-1</Y>
                        </Difference>
                        <Absolute>
                            <X>192</X>
                            <Y>148</Y>
                        </Absolute>
                    </MotionVector>
                </SubMacroBlock>
            </MacroBlock>
         </Slice>
        </SubPicture>
</Picture>
```

as you can see the order of the tags to achieve the `X` and `Y` value is `Picture/SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/MotionVector/Absolute/X`but some times this order is `Picture/SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/SubMacroBlock/MotionVector/Absolute/X`so when I use this code

```
 abs_x_tag=list(qpy_node.text for qpy_node in root.findall('Picture/SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/SubMacroBlock/MotionVector/Absolute/X'))
```

to extract all `X` values it can not extract all `X` values and also I have to calculate motion vectors for different frame types based on this tag

```
<TypeString>SLICE_TYPE_P</TypeString>
```

and based on these limitations I do not know how can I extract the `X` and `Y` values for each frame type separately. I can extract all `X` and `Y` values using the mentioned code but I do not know how do I find these values based on the type of frame. could you please help me with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Could  plz you attach full XML node and an example of desired output.

Comment: unfortunately, I can not attach my file. this XML file is about 26 Mb and when I want to add it using image attach I couldn't attach it. how do I attach my XML file?

Comment: Extract a **VALID** subset of the file and post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example how can you parse this xml with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Installing BeautifulSoup and lxml

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4 lxml
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


XML = """
<Picture id="1" poc="1">
        <GOPNr>0</GOPNr>
        <SubPicture structure="0">
            <Slice num="0">
                <Type>0</Type>
                <TypeString>SLICE_TYPE_P</TypeString>
                <NAL>
                    <Num>5</Num>
                    <Type>1</Type>
                    <TypeString>NALU_TYPE_SLICE</TypeString>
                    <Length>47048</Length>
                </NAL>
                <MacroBlock num="0">
                    <MotionVector list="0">
                        <RefIdx>0</RefIdx>
                        <Difference>
                            <X>184</X>
                            <Y>149</Y>
                        </Difference>
                        <Absolute>
                            <X>184</X>
                            <Y>149</Y>
                        </Absolute>
                    </MotionVector>
                </MacroBlock>
            </Slice>
        </SubPicture>
</Picture>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(XML, 'xml')

slices = soup.find_all('Slice')
for slice in slices:
    type = slice.find('TypeString').text
    print(f"Type: {type}")
    vectors = slice.find_all('MotionVector')
    for vector in vectors:
        print("Vector:")
        difference = vector.find('Difference')
        difference_x = difference.find('X').text
        difference_y = difference.find('Y').text

        absolute = vector.find('Absolute')
        absolute_x = absolute.find('X').text
        absolute_y = absolute.find('Y').text

        # Here you know type and x, y and type

        print(f"Difference: {difference_x}, {difference_y}")
        print(f"Absolute: {absolute_x}, {absolute_y}")
```

Output:

```
Type: SLICE_TYPE_P
Vector:
Difference: 184, 149
Absolute: 184, 149
```

Comment: what is XML? I put the address of xml file instead of 'XML' but it produces this error:
soup = BeautifulSoup('E:/UGCVIDEOS/9_9.xml', 'xml')
D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:350: MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning: "E:/UGCVIDEOS/9_9.xml" looks like a filename, not markup. You should probably open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup.
  MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning

Comment: @david You should pass the file content to the BeautifulSoup: `text = open('E:/UGCVIDEOS/9_9.xml').read()`, then `soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'xml')`

Comment: it works but I have to analyze about 2000 XML files and it is really time-consuming, do you have any suggestions to speed it up?

Comment: @david You can split xml files by several folders and run in separate python processes. So, you utilize all your CPU cores. Test your solution on several files and leave the processes for a night :) Also, be sure to make some progress logs, like '5 of 500 files processed...'

Comment: @ Eugenij Thank you. I am really new to Python and so I am not familiar with splitting the XML file and other suggestions that you said. could you please help me with this issue or introduce any tutorial about this?

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in a simple way and see the output below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

SampleXML = """
<Picture id="1" poc="1">
        <GOPNr>0</GOPNr>
        <SubPicture structure="0">
            <Slice num="0">
                <Type>0</Type>
                <TypeString>SLICE_TYPE_P</TypeString>
                <NAL>
                    <Num>5</Num>
                    <Type>1</Type>
                    <TypeString>NALU_TYPE_SLICE</TypeString>
                    <Length>47048</Length>
                </NAL>
                <MacroBlock num="0">
                    <MotionVector list="0">
                        <RefIdx>0</RefIdx>
                        <Difference>
                            <X>184</X>
                            <Y>149</Y>
                        </Difference>
                        <Absolute>
                            <X>184</X>
                            <Y>149</Y>
                        </Absolute>
                    </MotionVector>
                </MacroBlock>
            </Slice>
        </SubPicture>
</Picture>
"""
# use below commented lines if you are reading from xml file and replace XMl absolute path with <InputXML>
# tree = ET.parse(r"<InputXML>")
# root = tree.getroot()
root = ET.fromstring(SampleXML)
TypeString = root.findall("./SubPicture/Slice/TypeString")
print("TypeString: ", TypeString[0].text)
abs_x_tag = root.findall("./SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/MotionVector/Absolute/X") or root.findall("./SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/SubMacroBlock/MotionVector/Absolute/X")
print("abs_x_tag: ", abs_x_tag[0].text)
```

Output:

TypeString:  SLICE_TYPE_P

abs_x_tag:  184